# D3 timeScale remove month boundary tick

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build a box plot representing stats of a lot of data(x-time, y-time) The idea is to use d3.extent() to get the domain and then feed it to timeScale to get ticks in nicely chosen intervals. Then I calculate stats for data points between the ticks. Example below:[image]
The approach works well most of the time. Except for the 1st day of the month which creates an additional tick in an uneven spacing ( see above "Wed 31, June" ). I'm currently calculating bar widths and positions manually assuming that the ticks are spaced evenly so the whole chart gets broken.

The data can span any range of time from a week to couple years, so dynamic ticks are required.

Any ideas how to remove the additional tick or make all the ticks spread evenly?

EDIT. Not sure if removing the tick is going to do the trick... probably even spacing is more important here. I looked up other people's questions about similar problems but I'm still confused how to solve my problem.
I've just started using D3 so forgive me if the question is trivial. I'll be happy if you just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please, post your axis generator.

Comment: I don't think I'm using any. I use axisBottom and depend on the ticks generated by scaleTime

Comment: d3.axisBottom(x)
                .tickSize(4)
                .tickPadding(this.viewBox.height - y(0))

Comment: Yes, that's what we call "axis generator".

Comment: good to know ;) I'm a d3 noob